# Automatic Vertical image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help to create a vertical image slider which slides the image automatically with interval.

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item">
<img src="img/1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="img/2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="img/3.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="img/4.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 3000 });
});
</script>
```

I need the same thing vertically.

Comment: You can see the other carousals for hint which save a lot of time and queries here.

Comment: It is a horizontal one. I used the twitter bootstrap carousel. Its for horizontal only. But is it possible to make it vertical here in jquery?..

Comment: In jquery everything is possible but we have to code for that which is not easy here bro.

Comment: You can also use CSS3 for this using the `@keyframes` rule.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) or [bxslider](http://bxslider.com). Take a look at [this](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html) and [this](http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel) for vertical-scroll example pf jCarousel and [this](http://bxslider.com/examples/vertical-slideshow) for bxslider example

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how to use CSS3 and HTML5 to get the effect of a vertical slider.

https://jsfiddle.net/cd3oezzj/

Uses `@keyframes` rule. `@-webkit-keyframes` may be required for some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Answer (score 0):

just put this below:

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src= "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
     $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 2000, cycle: true });
     }); 
</script>
```

plz maimtain the sequence as i maintain...